# Ubuntu 15.10 crashing randomly

Tags: unity, grub2, launcher, 15.10, crash

Please forgive me as I am new to Ubuntu. Randomly, this thing which I think is called "Unity" will crash, and I will lose system vitals required to operate the computer.

The icons in the top right disappear, removing my ability to see the time, change the volume, and most importantly, safely restart the system. The bar on the left side of the screen, which I think it's called the "Launcher", will also disappear. Sometimes the entire thing will disappear, other times only the icons. 90% of the time when it crashes, the keyboard will also be disabled, preventing me from switching to TTY or opening a terminal. Most builtin applications will crash as well, such as Firefox, Files, Ubuntu Software Center, and Terminal.

I've only been using Ubuntu for about a week, and this all started not long after installing Ubuntu, when I allowed Ubuntu to install some updates to Ubuntu base, and some other things I can't remember.

After installing those updates (I feel this is worth noting). Grub, the boot thingy, also stopped working to some extent, being unable to boot Ubuntu. I did find a work around though. I go into "Advanaced options for ubuntu", I am presented with 6 options. If I choose "Ubuntu, with Linux 4.2.0-16-generic" or "Ubuntu, with Linux 4.2.0-16-generic(upstart)" Ubuntu will boot fine, and if i select ""Ubuntu, with Linux 4.2.0-16-generic(recovery)" then recovery will boot fine. "Ubuntu" at the main boot screen, and the other options available in "Advanced options for ubuntu" will result in either "attempted read/write hd0" or something to do with a kernal.

I have looked around, and nothing seems to be quite my problem.

EDIT: It'd be nice if I could get an answer to this soon as it is starting to affect my work efficiency. The last crash happened after only 3 minutes of use.

Comment: If you're a new to Ubuntu, you should consider using the Long Term Support versions (LTS), like 14.04. It's pretty stable, you'll more available articles about it and it'll receive support for 5 years, as opposite of only 9 months of 15.10.

Comment: Would downgrading Ubuntu not make me lose my files @RaelGugelminCunha ?

Comment: You can't downgrade afaik. Generally the best practice is to just back up your folders using a thumbdrive, or google drive, and resync them when you install fresh.

Comment: @Akiva Then for now im going to stay with 15.10 and just wait for a response on this. How would i go about getting support, as i am most certainly still within 9 months of installing.

Comment: You get support via the drivers, patches, and security updates. You can purchase official support if you wish, or you can use forums like this, or #ubuntu on IRC.  Here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/IRC/ChannelList

Comment: Also it would be nice if you kept your question more succinct and to the point. Its kind of hard to parse your issue. It almost sounds like a hardware issue,

Comment: Usually I move /home and /var to separate partitions. Then I can reinstall and format the system partition without lose my documents/music/video. This way I can test several Ubuntu versions.

Comment: @Akiva The issue is that Ubuntu 15.10 won't stop randomly crashing Unity

Comment: You should post the error about the kernel. Take a look at `/var/log/kern.log` as well.